# Switch boolean value

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a test app that switches a boolean value in Firestore. Now i retrieve that value, which is true. But how to do when i tap on switch that value change to false in Firestore?

```
StreamBuilder<List<Product>>(
    stream: ProductService().products,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return DataTable(
          columns: [
            DataColumn(
              label: Text('isActive'),
            ),
          ],
          rows: snapshot.data.map((products) {
            return DataRow(cells: [
              DataCell(
                Switch(
                    value: products.isActive,
                    onChanged: (bool notActive) {
                      setState(() {
                        products.isActive = notActive
                      });
                    }),
              ),
            ]);
          }).toList(),
        );
      }
      return Container();
    });
```

In `FireStore` when creating product value 'isActive' is always true.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define how you set your value in FireStore in your service, in your case which is `ProductService`.

Refers to my code on how you update a document in FireStore,

```dart
final Firestore db = Firestore.instance;
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection('COLLECTION_NAME').document('DOCUMENT_NAME');

Future<void> toggleActive(bool active) {
    return docRef.setData({
        'isActive': active,
    }, merge: true);
}
```

Hope it helps.